# Technologies recommendation for a PWA project that will use google maps javascript API

Tags: google-maps, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I need recommendations for a PWA. My project is to map my University using the Google Maps API. Each University location will be defined by a google API Label.

I need recommendations:

Which database to use for storing location data?
What language is most recommended to use for push notifications?

Comment: Please post your question completely in English.

Comment: Please not that because of W3C intransagence your students with not receive Geolocation updates in the background of when the phone is asleep. This means the student phone cannot tell the server where they are so the server cannot decide if they need notifying :-(

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [series of articles about PWAs](https://dev.to/paco_ita/a-gentle-introduction-to-progressive-web-apps-step-1-24da), going from theory to deeper in code specs. Maybe you can start there to build a general overview about this topic and better understand the components involved.

I wrote a PWA as personal project using Angular, Cloud Firestore (as noSQL Db and offline persistence) and Google Maps API to provide the maps and metadata about some selected locations.

You can switch Angular with anything else you feel more familiar (as Rusian said), like Vue, React, PHP...

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious recommendation: use tools you know best. More to the subject: you can work with google maps api almost from any framework. It only depends on how much you like the way the framework itself tailored.